# PHP arrays, trying to match three numbers

Tags: php, arrays

im trying to match three or more numbers from two seperate arrays, but all i have so far is code matching the first three numbers, when I need it to compare all six numbers and see if there are three in common ? I have tried comparing all six numbers but it does not work. Any help is appreciated. Jessica

```
foreach($lottoTickets as $y => $yvalue)
{   
if($i == 0)
{
    echo " ";
}
else{
    if((($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][0]) || ($winner[0] ==   $lottoTickets[$y][1]) || ($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][2]) || ($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][3]) || ($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][4]) || ($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][5])) && 
    (($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][0]) || ($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][1]) || ($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][2]) || ($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][3]) ||($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][4]) || ($winner[1] == $lottoTickets[$y][5])) &&
    (($winner[2] == $lottoTickets[$y][0]) || ($winner[2] == $lottoTickets[$y][1]) || ($winner[2] == $lottoTickets[$y][2]) || ($winner[0] == $lottoTickets[$y][3]) ||($winner[2] == $lottoTickets[$y][4]) || ($winner[2] == $lottoTickets[$y][5])))

    echo "<b>Three winning numbers ID = </b>" .$y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array_diff) for that purpose.
It returns an array containing all differences within two given arrays.

If you determine the differences between the user's lotto ticket and the correct numbers, you get the amount of wrong numbers.

Subtracting that integer from 6* gives you the amount of correctly chosen numbers.

```
foreach ($lottoTickets as $y => $yvalue) {
  if($i == 0)
  {
    echo " ";
  }

  else {
    $diff = array_diff($lottoTickets[$y], $winner);
    $correctNumbers = 6 - count($diff);

    if ($correctNumbers >= 3) {
      echo "<b>(At least) three winning numbers ID = </b>" . $y;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is also a minimal working sample: http://codepad.org/OWrdv5Xe

<sup>*) 6 is not a magic number here (→ Lotto)</sup>

---

As for why your code does not work (in all cases): it is because you only compare the first three correct numbers to the chosen ones. You have to compare all numbers. This involves having a counter variable for storing the amount of correctly chosen numbers.

If you really want to stick with your current solution, at least use [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array) and a loop. **But** the solution I provided at the top of my answer is really better.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew there had to be an easier/cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: In case someone wants to see the value of $diff, see this: http://codepad.org/v0cXkRJs

Comment: @pablofiumara Thanks! I updated my answer (I also improved your snippet by adding comments and some echo's).

Comment: @ComFreek: You are welcome! You are answer is much clearer now. That is why I upvoted it.